# Passing complex type parameters into a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a WSDL endpoint which I've added to my Project as a Service Reference called ContentService, works out fine.

Then in my code, I'm declaring the client, and the associated request, UnitInfo like this:

```
  // Both of these declarations work fine    
  ContentService.ContentServiceClient client = new   ContentService.ContentServiceClient();
  ContentService.UnitInfo request = new ContentService.UnitInfo();
```

I need to pass in the following info though:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <UnitInfo xmlns="http://www.acme.com/acme/2007/02">
            <!-- Optional -->
            <POS>
                <!-- Optional -->
                <Source>
                </Source>
            </POS>
            <!-- Optional -->
            <UnitInfos>
                <!-- Optional -->
                <Units HowMany="?">
                    <!-- Optional -->
                    <Amenities/>
                    <!-- Optional -->
                </Units>
            </UnitInfos>
        </UnitInfo>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

The problem is that my request variable has null for the UnitInfos property, how can I set the 'HowMany' attribute on the Units section before sending.  Also, how do I send the request to the endpoint?

All the examples on the web show a simple add where you are sending two ints, but here I need to send a more complicated structure over.

Comment: This has nothing to do with web services. You simply need to fill in a correct instance of your request class.  How do you expect there to be any `UnitInfos` if you don't create any of them? Magic?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you usually see no diference between sending ints or something more complecated:

```
client.Send(new ContentService.UnitInfo());
```

Second. As you wrote `<UnitInfos>` and it will not exist in envelope, if `null` is set.-

Comment: Thanks @ie, I agree, I just want to send over let's say 5 as the 'HowMany', but how do I set that on the request variable?  Intellisense is only showing me the UnitInfos property and it is set to null, how do I tack on that value before sending?

Comment: @MarkKadlec you shouldn't do it manually, it should be done by the serialization engine authomatically.

Comment: So I would need to create an object to match the UnitInfo structure?  Do you mind providing sample code, I'm not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: I would imagine my call to be client.Send(request); , but how do I add the 'HowMany' property to the request object to equal 5 for example?

Comment: @MarkKadlec when you create a service reference, Visual Studio recreates  `UnitInfo` for you, so you usually should not do anything additional.

Comment: @MarkKadlec could you please provide service contract? or at least the code generated by adding service reference. Then I'll try to provide you some detailed sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73970/discussion-between-mark-kadlec-and-ie).

Comment: I think I understand you, so I would simply do, `request.UnitDescriptiveInfos[0].UpdatedAfter = DateTime.Parse("03/15/2015");` correct?  That seems ok, but the client doesn't have a .send() call, I'm using .net 4.0, is it something else?

Comment: As soon as I cannot see service contract I can only speculate. The `Send` call is one of such speculations. Please try to find the proper name in docs.

Comment: I would say that request building can looks so: `request.UnitDescriptiveInfos = new [] {new UnitDescriptiveInfo { UpdatedAfter = DateTime.Parse("03/15/2015") }}`. But it is a speculation again. If you provide service contract I can be more detailed.